# Design for manufacturability

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, manufacturing-process

I am a current EEE student and was wondering how the process of design for manufacturability works?

What are the technical and safety issues that a manufacturer focuses on when designing a product to mass produce and sell? For example how do they determine that the circuits/product will not stop working after 6 months?

Comment: People write entire books series about this topic, it will be impossible to give a real answer here.

Comment: Waaaaaay to broad a subject. Your best bet is Google. There are far too many things involved with each process to give an answer here

Comment: You're asking two broad questions. DFM and design for reliability are not the same.

Comment: @jalalipop I didn't realize they were different things but yeah sorry I do recognise how broad of a question it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just a noob in electronics, but I will do my best to think of some considerations:

- Checking for each component's datasheet, that the ranges where the component work in are (well) within specifications (i.e. not more current/voltage than specified)
- Endurance tests, probably with voltage/current close to the range, maybe even slightly above it. Although endurance tests are not done for more than hours/days probably (per test).
- For safety (not related to 6 months) there are a lot of rules, depending per country. Manufacturers should apply these rules in their products.
- Probably also 'misuse' by users is taken care of, like not accidentally using the device with an adapter reversed (by using diodes).
- EMF tests or other tests with hash conditions, like noisy environments for motors/sensors/communication devices.